# Installing Anaconda on Ubuntu 14.04 - installing mrjob

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, mrjob, installation-package

The installation went fine, except for the last three packages:

```
mrjob, pattern, and seaborn
```

I was able to install these from a terminal, however they installed into my old Python environment and not into the anaconda environment. How can I install these packages into my anaconda environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages are not available in Anaconda. So you need to use the pip command to install them. The package will be installed in your active conda environment.

```
pip install mrjob
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `conda` to install them. For mrjob and pattern, you may need find them on [Binstar](https://binstar.org/search?q=mrjob). It looks like `conda install -c chdoig -c nbsantos mrjob pattern seaborn` should work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the syntax there...  I tried:  $  conda install -c chdoig -c hargup mrjob  .   Sadly that didn't work (Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: mrjob).  I had to use "hargup" instead of "nbsantos" for my system.  Any ideas??

Comment: That means the channels I chose didn't have Linux builds. If you find one that does (like hargup) you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Python environment uses Anaconda, then you should do this command
`conda install -c conda-forge -n [your-env-name] mrjob`.

It would take mrjob packages from [conda-forge repository](https://conda-forge.org/).